# An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause

Tags: sql, correlated-subquery

I'm trying to build a query that groups and sums two different fields for the same ID.  Then I'm trying to extract only the records that are different where the grouped total is different from the summed total.

For example - The sum([EstimatedEmployeesAtLocation]) should equal the grouped Estimatedtotalemployees is the same for each record.

This is what three records would look like

```
ID                            1,1,1
Estimatedtotalemployees       10,10,10
EstimatedEmployeesAtLocation  6,2,1
```

I know the issue is something with using an aggregate function in the where clause, because the query works until I add the where clause.  But I don't know the correct syntax.  Can someone please advise?

```
select ID, Estimatedtotalemployees, sum([EstimatedEmployeesAtLocation]) emploc
from Rawdata
where sum([EstimatedEmployeesAtLocation]) <> EstimatedTotalEmployees
group by policyNumber, EstimatedTotalEmployees
```

This is the error message.An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.  I'm just starting to use SQL beyond basic querying so any help is much appreciated -

Answer (score 0):

SQLs are evaluated in roughly the following order:

- FROM - the data is joined
- WHERE - the data is filtered
- GROUP BY - the data is aggregated
- SELECT - the result set is produced

You can't use a SUM(...) in a WHERE clause because it hasn't been calculated yet; it's done as part of the GROUP BY and SELECT

You also can't have ID in your select list because you haven't grouped by it.

You might be better off asking a new question/editing some detail into this one that sets out what raw data you have (and please put it with columns across the top, rows downwards, like SSMS shows you), what you've tried (e.g the above sql), and what your desired result is (again, rows run horizontally and columns run vertically, otherwise someone will end up giving you a pivot). Right now you seem to have given the raw data but have labelled it as the result data, and it looks the wrong way round so I'm not sure if it needs rotating or not

Here's my best stab at what you're after:

```
select ID, MAX(Estimatedtotalemployees), SUM([EstimatedEmployeesAtLocation]) 
from Rawdata
group by ID
having SUM([EstimatedEmployeesAtLocation]) <> MAX(EstimatedTotalEmployees)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and thank you also for your tips on how to ask questions and how to format the data as I know I will be asking more questions.  I really, really appreciate the help - you made my day.

Comment: You're welcome; as another brief orientation to StackOverflow - if you find an answer useful, click the up arrow. If one answer is what you chose as "works best for me" you click the tick to turn it green and mark it as accepted. You can upvote any answers, including ones you mark as accepted or even in questions you didn't ask, but you can(/and should, so we know your problem is solved) only mark-as-accepted one answer per each one of your questions